# syntax for setting up ssh tunnels

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I cannot wrap my head around ssh parameters for setting ssh tunnels.
Today I have googled these two commands for local forward.

```
ssh -f -L 2222:myserver.com:22 localhost -N
ssh -f -L 2222:localhost:22 myserver.com -N
```

The result seems to be the same for both of them.

Is there any difference in how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are differences when `localhost` and `myserver.com` resolve to different addresses (different machines).

Because your examples use the port `22` which is a standard port for SSH, I changed this number to `222` in my answer. The point is to tell the difference between the carrier SSH connection (to port `22` by default) and the target of the SSH tunnel.

> The result seems to be the same for both of them.

To make it clear for future readers: both commands make data entering `localhost:2222` go to the process that listens on the port `222` (`22` in the original question) at the `myserver.com` machine. We're talking about TCP ports here.

---

#### 1.

```
ssh -f -L 2222:myserver.com:222 localhost -N
```

With this command

- you need SSH access to the `localhost`;
- the SSH connection is local so any encryption it provides is just unnecessary computational work;
- the SSH server passes the data to the remote `myserver.com:222` exactly as it enters the local port `2222`, so **there is no additional encryption at this stage** (the data entering the local port `2222` may or may not be encrypted beforehand, this is independent);
- `myserver.com` sees the connection to its port `222` as coming from the outside (from your localhost which is not theirs `localhost`), so **the port `222` must not be blocked by firewall there**.

If you make your connection directly to `myserver.com:222` instead of `localhost:2222` the result should be the same because `myserver.com` won't tell the difference. That's why I consider this first command almost useless. (Why "almost"? – I'll explain at the end.)

---

#### 2.

```
ssh -f -L 2222:localhost:222 myserver.com -N
```

In this case

- you need SSH access to `myserver.com`;
- the SSH connection goes to another machine, **all the data is encrypted at this stage**;
- the SSH server decrytps the tunneled data and passes it to its own `localhost`, i.e. locally to the same machine;
- `myserver.com` sees the connection to its port `222` as coming from itself (locally) and **this should pass the firewall** because it's uncommon to block local connections; the listening process may even listen on the loopback interface only.

**It's quite clear to me this second command is the superior one.**

---

One scenario when the first command may be useful: if another (third) computer needs to access `myserver.com:222` and has no route to it, connecting to the port `2222` of your localhost (which is not its `localhost`) may be a solution. Note this requires `-g` option to `ssh` command (refer to `man ssh` to learn more). You can use any of the two commands for this purpose, but if you have no SSH access to `myserver.com` then the second command won't work.

Well, one could build a tunnel entirely from the third computer. The command would be:

```
ssh -f -L 2222:myserver.com:222 ssh-server -N
# then connect to their own localhost:2222
```

Obviously this requires SSH access to `ssh-server` (your `localhost`). But let's suppose the third computer belongs to your friend with no SSH access to `ssh-server`. You (with the access) can build the tunnel for them with the first command and `-g` option. They should connect to `ssh-server:2222` then.

Answer (score 0):

The net effect is the same, you end up with a tunnel from port `2222` on `localhost` to port `22` on `myserver.com`, but they do work a bit differently.  In the first example you are doing `ssh localhost` and adding some flags, so fundamentally, you're logging into `localhost` again.  In the second example, however, you are running `ssh myserver.com` with some flags, so you are creating a connection to the remote host.

`-L` take (here) 3 arguments, the port on the local machine that's one end of the tunnel, the host (after the connection is established) on the other end that's the target of the tunnel, and finally the port on the remote end of the tunnel.

If you tunnel to `localhost` and create a tunnel to `myserver.com` you have a connection to, well, `myserver.com`.  If, on the other hand, you connect to `myserver.com` and tunnel to `localhost` from the remote side of the connection you have a connection, once again, to `myserver.com`.

So the net effect ends up being the same thing, but the host to which your `ssh` must authenticate (in order to setup the tunnel) is different.